# Name files with values from array

Tags: arrays, xml, file, powershell, msxml

I want to name files with values stored in an array.

I have a folder with some .xml files in. I have processed the files with MSXSL, and have written the output files to an output folder.

I want to name the output files with the same name as the original files. However at the moment my script is calling the files `[0].xml`, `[1].xml`, `[2].xml`, etc.

Here is my script so far:

```
[array]$files = Get-ChildItem c:\powershell\ -Filter *.xml    
[array]$names = Get-ChildItem c:\powershell\ -Filter *.xml | Select-Object Name

$current = 0

foreach ($file in $files) {
    c:\powershell\msxsl.exe $files[$current] transform.xslt -o c:\powershell\output\$names[$current].xml
    $current ++
}
```

I am obviously messing up the main line of my for loop.

`MSXSL.EXE` takes the `-o` switch, which names the output file. I have tried to reference elements of my `$names` array but it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to maintain 2 arrays, nor incrementing the counter manually.

For the orignal file path, use the `FullName` property, and for the name alone, use `Name`:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem c:\powershell\ -Filter *.xml    

foreach ($file in $files) {
    c:\powershell\msxsl.exe $file.FullName transform.xslt -o $(Join-Path 'c:\powershell\output' $file.Name)
}
```